# ‘i’ was not declared in this scope for (i = 0; i <= years; i++)

Tags: c++, loops

For some reason, myprogramminglab keeps saying that I have not declared what 'i' and I don't understand why.

```
 #include <iostream>

     using namespace std;

     int main()
 {
     int years;
     double cost, inflaRate;

    cout<<"Enter the current price of pencils:";
    cin >> cost;
    cout<<"Enter the number of years in the future that 
        you will buy the pencil:";
    cin >> years;

    cout<<"Enter the inflation rate as a percentage." << 
endl;
    cin >> inflaRate;

   inflaRate /= 1;

    cout << "The price of pencils will be " << cost;

   for (i = 0; i <= years; i++) //Keeps telling me I have not declared 'i' here
 {
 cost += (cost*inflaRate);
 }
    cout << cost << "in" << years << "years." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0;`, maybe? You should read a good C++ book.

Comment: Not really a typo, but close enough.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason ...

That reason is because you *haven't* actually declared `i`. You can fix that with a simple change to your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= years; i++) // No longer complains you have not declared 'i' :-)
//   ^^^
//  Declare it!
```